# Is there an effect on the speed of a query when using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

The other day I found the `FOUND_ROWS()` ([here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)) function in MySQL and it's corresponding `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option. The later looks especially useful (instead of running a second query to get the row count).

I'm wondering what speed impact there is by adding `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to a query?

I'm guessing it will be much faster than runnning a second query to count the rows, but will it be a lot different. Also, I have found limiting a query to make it much faster (for example when you get the first 10 rows of 1000). Will adding `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to a query with a small limit cause the query to run much slower?

I know I can test this, but I'm wondering about general practices here.

Comment: Similar to a previous question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186588/which-is-fastest-select-sqlcalcfoundrows-from-table-or-select-count/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186588/which-is-fastest-select-sqlcalcfoundrows-from-table-or-select-count/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` the query will be execute as if no `LIMIT` was set, but the result set sent to the client will obey the `LIMIT`.

---

Update: for COUNT(*) operations which would be using only the index, `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is slower ([reference](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/)).

Comment: So essentially it ends up being the same as running the entire query without the limit?

Comment: Almost - there is overhead in sending the result set to the client, especially over the network.

Comment: Also see my update for once case where it is considerably slower.

Answer (score 3):

When I was at the MySQL Conference in 2008, part of one session was dedicated to exactly this - benchmarks between `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and doing a separate `SELECT`.

I believe the result was that there was no benefit to `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` - it wasn't faster, in fact it may have been slower. There was also a 3rd way.

Additionally, you don't always need this information, so I would go the extra query route.

I'll try to find the slides...

**Edit:** Hrm, google tells me that I actually liveblogged from that session: http://beerpla.net/2008/04/16/mysql-conference-liveblogging-mysql-performance-under-a-microscope-the-tobias-and-jay-show-wednesday-200pm/. Google wins when memory fails.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it would be slightly faster for queries that you need the number of rows know, but would incur and overhead for queries that you don't need to know.

The best advice I could give is to try it out on your development server and benchmark the difference. Every setup is different.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use as few proprietary SQL extensions as possible when developing an application (or actually not using SQL queries at all). Doing a separate query is portable, and actually I don't think MySql could do better at getting the actual information than re-querying. Btw. as the page mentions the command has some drawbacks too when used in replicated environments.