# Displaying results from mysql database gradually

Tags: php, mysql

So i'm working with huge MYSQL database of english words. the list has upwards of 180k words. Im trying to run a query, and then compute something using every word in the database. The problem is the database is so big, and it seems to be freezing my browser (Im working locally with MAMP). Is there a way I can do five queries at a time, instead of trying to run through the whole thing, so i can see the results coming in gradually in my browser? Heres the code:

```
<?php
require 'class.thing.php';
require 'db_config.php';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM words") or die ("Could not complete query");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $word = $row['word'];
    $compute = $word."thing";
    $finished = new method( $compute );

   if ($finished->successfull()) {
      echo "<br/>";
      echo "worked!";
      echo "<br/>";
   } else {
      echo "uh oh..";
   }

}

?>
```

** im looking for something like:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM words") or die ("Could not complete query LIMIT 0,5");

get results
```

wait 5 seconds

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM words") or die ("Could not complete query LIMIT 0,5");

get results
```

etc...

Comment: Assuming 1 word per row in your words table, 180k rows is not many rows at all.

Comment: What's the code for the `method` class?

Comment: Please show your schema for the `words` table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql Data - Best way to implement paging?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799193/mysql-data-best-way-to-implement-paging)

Comment: its not about the way it looks, its that i think too many queries are freezing my computer.

Comment: @user1502867 You are only running one query in your original code. If your browser is actually locking up, then it is most likely because you are sending a LOT of data to the browser (and possibly running some javascript on it?). However, the code that you've provided so far does not show where you are sending this data to the client/browser.

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at this related question:

[What is the best way to paginate results in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-sql-server)

Note that you can compare words in SQL alphabetically (check whether your settings use case sensitive sorting or not), so you can do something like:

`SELECT * FROM words WHERE word <= "ferrous" ORDER BY word`

If you're using an auto-incrementing id, you can use that to subdivide as well (it'd probably be easier).

**EDIT:**

As pointed out below, you can use `LIMIT` in MySQL.

Example:

`SELECT * FROM words LIMIT 0, 1000`

(This would display the first 1000 results).

Comment: That link is for MS SQL Server. With MySQL, we use `LIMIT`.

Comment: Also, with the default collation in MySQL, string comparisons are NOT case sensitive. Maybe you can further explain how that relates to the question.