# Can you retrieve id from a drop down list before posting

Tags: php

I'm doing a program in php where I have set up table rms having fields rid, type and room.  Type denotes whether its standard, cheap,  expensive etc and room denotes the total number of rooms available.

I want to have a ddl to display the type and cascading ddl that display rooms like 1,2,3, etc up to total number available.

For example if I chose cheap from first ddl and its total rooms is 30 in the table, then the next ddl should show 1 to 30 in the list.

I was thinking about retrieving id from the first ddl to fetch the room corresponding to it but seems to have problems. Can it be done?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. In more than one way. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

[From the MySQL documentation:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html#id1026131)

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements).
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
> ```
>
> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter.
>   This statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;
> ```
>
> With one argument, the value specifies the number of rows to return from the beginning of the result set:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5;     # Retrieve first 5 rows
> ```
>
> In other words, LIMIT row_count is equivalent to LIMIT 0, row_count.

[From stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799193/mysql-data-best-way-to-implement-paging)