# MySQL split table query using varchar column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL which I want to query parallel by executing multiple select statements that select 
non-overlapping equal parts from the table, like:

```
1. select * from mytable where col between 1 and 1000
2. select * from mytable where col between 1001 and 2000
...
```

The problem is that the col in my case is varchar. How can I split the query in this case?
In Oracle we can operate with NTILE in combination with rowids. But I didn't find a similar approach in case of MySQL.
That's why my thinking is to hash the col value and mod it by the number of equal parts I want to have.
Or instead of hashing, dynamically generated rownums could be used.

What would be an optimal solution considering that the table big (xxxM rows) and I want to avoid full table
scans for each of the queries?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3799223/1662973

Answer (score 0):

You can use `limit` for the purpose of paging, so you will have:

```
1. select * from mytable limit 0, 1000
2. select * from mytable limit 1000, 1000
```

Comment: If possible, I want to avoid full table scans.

Comment: You still want to read from the table, right? So how you want to avoid "full table scans"? What do you refer to as "full table scans"? As far as I know, limit 0, 1000 will not read all the table, it will stop reading after the first 1000 records matching your criteria is found.

Comment: In case of Oracle you have the rowid which points to the physical address of the given row. I'm looking for a similar approach (or another, optimal one) for MySQL. The problem with limit A, B is, that it yields to A+B rows scan. I.e: A+B records are retrieved and then A recods are dropped. For a webapp using this kind of pagination is fine but for retrieving 1B rows it's not

Answer (score 0):

you can use casting for varchar column to integer like this cast(col as int)

Regards 
Tushar

Comment: How do you cast a character sequence to integer?

Answer (score 0):

Without scanning fulltable, it will produce results

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
ORDER BY ID
OFFSET 0 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```