# Processing ResultSet of 5 million records to JSON object to avoid performance issues

Tags: java, json, resultset

```
while(resultSet.next()){    
    for (int c = 1; c <= metaData.getColumnCount(); c++){    
        String columnName = metaData.getColumnName(c);    
        Object value = resultSet.getString(columnName);     
        record.put(columnName, value);    
    }    
}
```

above while loop runs for 5 million times multiplied by no of columns. is there any best way to implement an efficient way to handle it..?

Comment: How about change your design not to run **5 million times multiplied by no of columns** ? :D

Comment: Is there any other way rather than just looping with while loop and forloop..? like converting entire resultset in to JSONObject directly..?

Comment: You have many options like, server side caching, fetch only needs from server, write stored procedures, add more filters from client side to narrow the queries etc. just look in abstract view and try to find a way.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do it with `Pagination` rather than sending a big `json` chunk back in the response. Not only it increases memory/CPU usage but also it incurs a lot if network traffic. Plus performance issues in Front End in processing and rendering such a big response.

In `pagination`, you would probably return first `n` records along with metadata (i.e. total number of records, total number of pages, current page etc). If you are using `Spring`, have a look at [this](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-seven-pagination/) pagination example.

At DB layer, you can implement it depending on database type (e.g. for `MySQL`, you can use `LIMIT`). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799193/mysql-data-best-way-to-implement-paging) SO answer explains how to do a pagination in `MySQL`.

Comment: is there any convenient way other than pagination for this..?

Comment: You could stream the data in bytes rather than wait for the whole `json` object to be constructed. But it is little complicated and requires change in a way Front End queries the data.