# Optimize MySQL query with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

It takes too much time to load when there are greater than 100000 records

```
 select meal_option_id,
            order_id, price,
            display_name,
            count, 
            deliveries.id
         from deliveries 
            inner join deliveries_meals
            on deliveries.id = deliveries_meals.delivery_id
            inner join meal_options
            on deliveries_meals.meal_option_id = meal_options.id
```

Comment: You shouldn't be asking the question in the title only.. Also returning 500000 records will take (some) time if you like it or not there is not really a way to optimize it.. Also why are you displaying 500000 records on one page nobody is going to read all that?

Comment: update your question and add  your table .schema .. explain what you mean for "getting too  loading"  (1 minute ,, 10 minute  ... 2 days) and explain  wahy you load 500000 and more

Comment: Questions about query performance ALWAYS require, as a minimum, CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables, and the results of the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: I think there isn't anything to optimise here since it's a pretty much basic query. You should try [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799193/mysql-data-best-way-to-implement-paging).

Comment: Follow the tips [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)