# Write a SQL query to select all products with pagination

Tags: mysql

Two tables are given. In one table we have following columns

```
productid
product_title
priority
categoryid
```

and in second table we have

```
id
productid
color
selling_price
stock
```

Write a SQL query to select all products in category id 306 with pagination
Lets say Result set would have 1000+ such products so we want to paginate the
results. In a single request only 100 result need to be return

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a text-book problem. 
Still trying to answer. The problem statement is not a straight problem. Here is my answer:

```
Select Top 100 * from table_2 where productid in (Select (productid, product_title, priority) from table_2 where (categoryid = 306));
```

Answer (score 0):

For paging please read the link :

[MySQL Data - Best way to implement paging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799193/mysql-data-best-way-to-implement-paging)

but your query is:

```
Select 
T1.productid
,T1.product_title
,T1.priority
,T1.categoryid
,T2.id
-- ,T2.productid
,T2.color
,T2.selling_price
,T2.stock
from First_Table T1
inner join to Second_Table T2 on T1.productid=T2.productid
where T1.categoryid=306
```