# select 7 rows from MySQL, except last 7, 14, ..., N*7 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

As far as I know to select last 7 rows from MySQL table in backward order, it needs to be done:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 7;
```

But I want to select penult 7 rows.
After that I want to select 7 rows, except 14 last rows, etc...

Thereby, I wonder what sql query it should be to select 7 rows, except last N * 7 rows?

Comment: Hint:  `limit`, `offset`.

Comment: Last or First is purely base on order, so I think you want to select  X rows from table but do not select ***The 7N rows***?

Comment: Yes, select X last rows without 7*N last rows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Data - Best way to implement paging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799193/mysql-data-best-way-to-implement-paging) Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3799293/14868997), which shows how to do keyset paging