# Is it possible to display mutliple results via UNION?

Tags: mysql, union

So I have the current query:

```
UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,3,concat(username),5,6 FROM users LIMIT 0,1
```

I am aware that "LIMIT 0,1" only makes it show 1 result, but is it possible to make it show around 5 - 20 results at a time,
so after I input the query I would want to get something like this:

```
username1, username2, username3, username4, username5
```

etc..
and when I run the query again (after modifying it of course),  I would want to get something like:

```
username6, username7, username8, username9, username10
```

Thanks :)

Comment: The "union" and expected output look nothing alike due to what appears to be transposing columns and rows and/or confusing addition of `concat` aggregation. I suspect you may be interested in "pagination" instead of (or even combined with) a union, eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799193/mysql-data-best-way-to-implement-paging (it is possible to use `order by..limit..offset` with a derived table).

Comment: `UNION`joins the result set vertically a join vertically and provide a complete [mre] i dpn't understand what you want as result a comma separated list?

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you are asking.  please do show the rest of your query, some sample data, and what results you want (for your series of queries)

Comment: This is presenting as an xy problem: 'how do I do x using y?', as opposed to 'how do I do x?'

Answer (score 0):

Are you after a comma separated list of usernames n long?  If so, then try group_concat:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(username)
FROM (
    SELECT username
    FROM users 
    LIMIT 0,5
) z
```

Comment: I don't understand this, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Does that query produce what you want it to produce?  Your question is not particularly clear about what output you are expecting.

Comment: The query you provided doesn't work for me, I am using UNION, the results I want it to display are the first 5 results, then the next 5 etc..

Comment: You want to display the first 5 usernames in one line, separated by commas?  And then the next 5 on one line, separated by commas, etc?  Or you want to display the first 5 on five different lines?

Comment: First 5 usernames in one line, separated by commas

Comment: That query should display the first five usernames on one line, separated by commas.  See this fiddle with a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ec856/1

Comment: How do I display the on different lines?

Comment: You want to display each username on a different line?

Comment: Yes I want to display each username on a different line

Comment: `SELECT username FROM users` will naturally do that