# Select Limit Data Each Time

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 32 records in my database and I select limit 10 records
but for next 10 records I did my best but I failed.

my code:

```
SELECT * FROM `records` LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Always use an `ORDER BY` when using `LIMIT`.

Comment: _”for next 10 records I did my best but I failed”_  What, exactly, did you try?

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799193/mysql-data-best-way-to-implement-paging what you are after?

Comment: Always look in the docs, they have "[**LIMIT** {[offset,] row_count | row_count **OFFSET** offset}]"  ([link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#:~:text=%5BLIMIT%20%7B%5Boffset%2C%5D%20row_count%20%7C%20row_count%20OFFSET%20offset%7D%5D))

Answer (score 0):

**Let us see why you failed :**

- you did not specify OFFSET in your query, thats why it will give you same result always.

**How we can fix this :**

- we can specify an offset I.e form where your next 10 will start count, by default offset will start form 0
- consider below updated query

```
SELECT * FROM `records` LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

- here next offset number could be your next page number

Comment: [Always use an ORDER BY when using LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77590952/select-limit-data-each-time#comment136788445_77590952)  (see comment on question)

Comment: it's not strictly necessary but highly recommended for consistent and predictable results

Comment: I think most users want "consistent and predictable results" ...

Comment: true, but the question does not have any idea about the field thats why not able to include  an order by in my answer.