# How to get count and records in single query

Tags: mysql

I have a picture table which consists for users pictures

```
Table Name:picture
Columns: picture_id primary key,auto increment
         user_id   INT  foreign key
         path VARCHAR(75)
```

user_id `1`consists of `50` images, I want first `20` image path according to `picture_id`
and `count` of all images of user_id `1`, that is `20` Records and `count` = `50`
with in a single query.

Comment: Why not get all the records and have a running count in PHP while you process the resultset?

Comment: I posted an answer mentioning `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` but it uses 2 queries so doesn't really answer your question. Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186588/which-is-fastest-select-sql-calc-found-rows-from-table-or-select-count) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little complicated, but you could do it via a subquery or a join.

One possibility would be:

```
select picture_id, 
  (select count(*) from pictures p1 where p1.user_id = pic.user_id) as num_pics
  from picture pic
  where pic.user_id = 1
  order by picture_id
  limit 20;
```

Comment: @RajneelJoshi  if you think this is the best answer to your problem , I think it's your duty to mark this as the correct answer! ;-)