# Which is faster: COUNT(DISTINCT Column) vs. COUNT(*) ... GROUP BY Column

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I'm using MySQL and I've read several times that `COUNT(*)` is generally faster than `COUNT(Column)`.

However, I need to get the `COUNT` of **distinct** rows.  From what I understand, I can do this in 2 different ways:

`a) SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Column) ...`

or

`b) SELECT COUNT(*) ... GROUP BY Column`

In general, which is **faster**?  If it *depends*, then what does it depend *on*?

Comment: I believe that you should have a look at `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and stop using `COUNT()` unless really needed.

Comment: @Peter need not be. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186588/which-is-fastest-select-sql-calc-found-rows-from-table-or-select-count

Comment: @nawfal I'm surprised. But keep in mind that it's a question from 2008... things could have changed a lot. And always use SQL_NO_CACHE for benchmarking

Comment: @Peter The comment confirming the answer is from Jul 11, 2012.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY column` returns the number of rows for each value of the grouped by column, not the number of groups.

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column) FROM table` returns the number of groups (although you can also get this using the row count from the `GROUP BY` query).

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the difference between those two, as the descriptions are somewhat confusing to a non-expert such as myself.  Thanks!

Comment: @Programmer If `SELECT column FROM table` returns `5, 6, 5, 7, 5, 6, 5` then `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY column` returns `4, 2, 1` (or variant thereof) while `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column) FROM table` returns `3`.