# select with count in sub select gives unwanted result due to group by clause

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT t.id_type, brand, model, countMod FROM types t  
    LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT p.id_type, brand, model, COUNT( model ) AS countMod 
           FROM products p  
           GROUP BY brand) p2 
    ON t.id_type = p2.id_type 
    WHERE t.id_type = "TCE" 
    ORDER BY brand
```

This query works alright but I lose the models which are grouped, of course, under each brand.
Is there a way to have the models listed and counted?
I.e. brand1, model1, model2, model3, countMod=3 -- brand2, model1, model2, countMod=2.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT brand, GROUP_CONCAT(model) models, COUNT(model) AS countMod
FROM products
GROUP BY brand
```

Answer (score 1):

try this::

```
SELECT 
t.id_type, 
brand,
GROUP_CONCAT(model SEPARATOR ',') as model, 
COUNT( model ) AS countMod 
FROM types t
LEFT JOIN products p  ON t.id_type = p.id_type
WHERE t.id_type = "TCE" 
GROUP BY brand
ORDER BY brand
```

Answer (score -1):

The recommended approach is the run two queries, one for the data and one with `COUNT()`.

With MySQL, you can also use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` (mostly if you have a `LIMIT` clause), however the performance of that is disputable, see [Which is fastest? SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS FROM `table`, or SELECT COUNT(*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186588/which-is-fastest-select-sql-calc-found-rows-from-table-or-select-count).

Comment: Is this an answer??
This should be a comment

Comment: @SashiKant I don't see why this should be a comment as it addresses the question directly: "Is there a way to have the models listed and counted?"