# Saving time in queries on sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

I have a scenario. I have say 300 records in my table. I execute a query to get the total count. Then , since i have to implement pagination,

I select the data from the same table using limits according t the count. I was thinking if i can get the count and data in a single query.? .

I tried below code:

`Select * ,count(*) as cnt from table;`

But this gave me the total count but only 1 record!

Is there a way to save my time exhausted in query and get results in a single query?

Comment: If you are doing pagination, using application code (php, .net, coldfusion, etc) might make this whole process easier.

Comment: @DanBracuk - Application code can't get a full table count on a `LIMIT`ed dataset.

Answer (score 4):

something like:

```
select t1.*,t2.cnt
from table t1
cross join (select count(*) as cnt from table) t2 
limit 'your limit for the first page'
```

or

```
select *,(select count(*) from table) as cnt
from table
limit 'your limit for the first page'
```

Comment: can u please explain first answer once.I dont have that much knowledge

Comment: I join the table with it's count number (a table with one row and one column). I display everything from the table and count number from the second one.

Comment: But Using this I would have to execute the count query every time. Isn't it?

Comment: The sql engine is smart enough not to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Using two queries might not be as bad as you may think, you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186588/which-is-fastest-select-sql-calc-found-rows-from-table-or-select-count) for more information.

Comment: `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is actually slower than running a separate `COUNT()` query.

Answer (score 0):

You can get information in data structure you mentioned, but there is really no reason to do it. There is no performance problem when you do two queries - one for getting rows count and another for data selection. You don't save anything when you try to select all information in *one* query. Do two simple queries instead, it will be better solution for your app - you will preserve its simplicity and clarity.