# Count records from a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this carousel that I want to make dynamic. To operate, the carousel must begin with a class

```
 <div class="item active">
```

and must stay out of the while loop. After the fourth record extract, the class must become simply

```
 <div class="item">
```

In summary:

```
   0 to 4 ->  <div class="item active"> 
   5 to 8 --><div class="item">
   9 to 12 --> <div class="item"> ....so on
```

How do I count the records extracted?
Thanks

```
 <?php
   $banner = "SELECT * FROM tbl_banner";
        $result_b = dbQuery($banner); 
        // here --> <div class="item active">  or <div class="item">  
          while($row_b = dbFetchAssoc($result_b)) {
            extract($row_b);
?>               
            <div class="col-md-3">
                 <div class="w-box inverse">
                    <div class="figure">
                       <img alt="" src="banner/<?php echo $img; ?>" class="img-responsive">
                         <div class="figcaption bg-2"></div>
                          <div class="figcaption-btn">
                             <a href="banner/<?php echo $img; ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-one theater"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Zoom</a>
                              <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-one"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> View</a>
                     </div>
               </div>
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xs-9">
                       <h2><?php echo $img_title; ?></h2>
                         <small><?php echo $img_desc; ?></small>
                             </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

  <?php                               
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: Well, you could use SQL's `COUNT()` function. http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlcount.php - there are more ways to do this though; of many.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `num_rows` to see how many rows were returned. Unfortunately from your question I can't tell whether you're using MySQL, MySQLi or PDO as it seems you pass all your queries into a class.

For MySQLi use the following:

```
$num = $result_b->num_rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_banner
```

OR

```
count( $res ); # in php
```

Also see: [Which is fastest? SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS FROM `table`, or SELECT COUNT(*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186588/which-is-fastest-select-sql-calc-found-rows-from-table-or-select-count)

Comment: How can i print a div class or other one with an MYSQL function??

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand....
I would like a result like this, explained in this way:

```
$query ="SELECT .....
 <div class="row">
  <div class="item active">
 while { 
  <div1>...</div>
  <div2>...</div>
  <div3>...</div>
  <div4>...</div>
} //end while

</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="item">

while {
<div4>...</div>
<div6>...</div>
<div7>...</div>
<div8>...</div> 

} //end while
```

etc etc