# Datatables speed up content display

Tags: php, database, laravel, datatables

In Datatables I use two query one to fetch records in that particular date range with server side pagination and another to get the total count of records in that particular date range. I am using **Postgresql database**.

```
select * from daily_txns where created_date <='2017-08-01' and created_date>='2017-07-01' and mid='0446721M0008690' order by created_date desc limit 10;

select count(mid) from daily_txns where created_date <='2017-08-01' and created_date>='2017-07-01' and mid='0446721M0008690';
```

Is this the correct way to do or is there any best approach for the same.
If the first query takes 20 sec then the second query takes 40 sec and the total time taken to display the result is more then 60 sec. How to overcome this problem.

Comment: in second query you can use `count(1)`

Comment: How long does it take to run each query in the database without loading anything into Datatables?

Comment: In first query you can get first 10 record and then you can give `order by` condition

Comment: I means you can use inner query

Comment: And for second query, as per SQL stander you can't reduce execution time with `count` , `order by` condition, because it's check all rows from your table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using postgres you can use this to reduce everything to one single query

```
select *, count(*) OVER() AS full_count from daily_txns where created_date <='2017-08-01' and created_date>='2017-07-01' and mid='0446721M0008690' order by created_date desc limit 10;
```

the "count(*) OVER() AS full_count" will 'ignore' the limits passed giving you the full count of possible elements

Comment: Can you please explain how can it's reduce execution time?

Comment: This is taking me much more time then executing both separately

Comment: How may records are in total on daily_txns table? Do you have any index on the table? What db are you using?

Comment: yes I have index for created_date and mid. I am using postgress database. There are 2,50,00,000 records in it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution depends on your table indexes and this answer only if indexes correct and you solutions like count(*) doesn't help you.

But sometimes you can try to use flag SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS for your query, but I recommend to read  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186588/which-is-fastest-select-sql-calc-found-rows-from-table-or-select-count) question and answer before use it.

Solution:

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from daily_txns where created_date <='2017-08-01' and created_date>='2017-07-01' and mid='0446721M0008690' order by created_date desc limit 10;
```

And query for get total records for your query

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an index to the columns mid and created_date on the table daily_txns. I'm also guessing that mid will be more restrictive than created_date, so I recommend using it first in the query so that the search reduces faster.

```
select * from daily_txns where mid='0446721M0008690' created_date <='2017-08-01' and created_date>='2017-07-01' order by created_date desc limit 10;

select count(mid) from daily_txns where mid='0446721M0008690' and created_date <='2017-08-01' and created_date>='2017-07-01';
```