# Regarding a query which is slowing down my WordPress site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a site with 100k+ posts and I am trying to use this query:

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5`

After searching for quite some time now, I came to understand that it's a pagination query.  The query takes too much time and is not efficient.

Does anyone know of a solution for this problem?

P.S. I have already searched the old answers but they do not provide any solution.

Comment: I would change this to `wp_posts.post_status IN( 'publish' ,'private')`  but i don't know where this SQL came from. And it's more of a readability thing, because it will be optimized to this anyway....  I would also try it without the Sorting as that can kill performance.

Comment: It executes by default so where the edit has to be happened..? in WP_Query.php file..?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS takes more time than two queries. Please check this link:

[Which is fastest? SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS FROM `table`, or SELECT COUNT(*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186588/which-is-fastest-select-sql-calc-found-rows-from-table-or-select-count)

Lot of users or developers have confirmed, you can read comments of users.

Try to use `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement to find number of records.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress you can use [WP_Query](http://WP_Query) for getting the posts found

```
$obj_name = new WP_Query($args);
$num = $obj_name->post_count;
```