# Why is my `sql_calc_found_rows` faster than `count(*)` in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, count

I know it has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186588/which-is-fastest-select-sql-calc-found-rows-from-table-or-select-count) that `sql_calc_found_rows` in MySQL is considered slower in many cases than running 2nd `count(*)` query. Moreover, we don't really have choice now, since `sql_calc_found_rows` is deprecated and will be removed from future versions of MySQL. But in my query, which consists of several left joins, multiple dynamic where clauses with limit and offset, adding `sql_calc_found_rows` with subsequent `FOUND_ROWS()` query has no overhead according to my tests. However, running `count(*)` as a second query with no limit and offset clause, to get number of total rows found, nearly *doubles* execution time. It seems very puzzling to me how every other source asserts that `count(*)` is faster due to internal optimizations, but in my practice it is considerably slower. It is worth noting that I have no indexes at this point. I would very much appreciate if anyone could bring a bit of clarity into this matter.

Comment: i assume you are talking about and benchmarked MySQL's InnoDB engine here?

Comment: Indeed, it is InnoDB. But at this developement stage database is local and not distributed.

Comment: Which MySQL version? `SELECT VERSION();` ... As the results are very depend on maybe the version, table indexes or InnoDB configuration (innodb_buffer_pool) for example this is a hard question to answer..

Comment: Please provide SELECT statements, CREATE TABLE statements of involved tables and output of EXPLAIN for SELECT statements if you want to get a specific optimization advice.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, it is 8.0.17.

Comment: From mine basic understanding when i looked in the source code  `sql_calc_found_rows` would require to load and process ("count") the complete resultset before limiting and cache the row_num for `FOUND_ROWS()` in the connection thread.. Meaning a **indexed** `COUNT(*)` query in a correctly configured MySQL Server ("`innodb_buffer_pool` mainly") and using InnoDB engine would be most likey (much) faster as the processed resultset is most likely (much) smaller.. On the other size using non-indexed tables then `sql_calc_found_rows` would be most likely faster..

Comment: The answer in your linked question was "it depends". It depends on if MySQL can use a different execution plan for two - actually different, just similar looking - queries. For the situation in the blog, it would depend on having a covering index or not. For your situation, it seems MySQL wasn't able to find a faster way. If you need help optimizing your concrete query, I point you to Naktibaldas comment. Btw, your title reads as if the single `sql_calc_found_rows`-query is faster than the single(!) `count(*)`-query, which, while not impossible, would be unusual and more interesting.

Comment: @Naktibalda, @Solarflare, I would've gladly provided the query statements, but in my case they involve joins with 10 tables, some of which have up to 80 columns. With regards to the title, allow me to elaborate: When I add `sql_calc_found_rows` to my query and execute `FOUND_ROWS()` as a next statment I observe no peroformance overhead, execution time is same with or without `sql_calc_found_rows`. However, if I do it the way it is suggested in MySQL docs, i.e. removing `LIMIT` and selecting `count(*)` in the 2nd statement, in total it takes 50% to 100% more time to complete both queries.

Comment: Well, I'd say that is the expected behaviour. There is no reason to assume otherwise for the *general* case. But also *generally* speaking, you can oftentimes optimize your query, e.g  with proper indexes or guiding MySQL to find the correct execution plan. (E.g. for the situation in the blog, a covering index will make the `sql_calc_found_rows`-query exactly(!) as fast as the `count`-query). But we cannot tell you how to optimize your query without seeing your query, just like for all other sql optimization questions too (may they be related to `sql_calc_found_rows` or not.)

Comment: Wrote it as an answer to elaborate a bit for the general situation (since you seem to either assume that it's always faster, or just want to know why it isn't in general). If you need help for your specific query, you would need to add your speciifc query (or, now, make a new question).

Comment: The `COUNT(*)` method is in worst case twice as slow. But it can be 10 times, 100 times or even 1000 times faster. It depends on the query. The worst case is when you use a high `OFFSET` (which is a rare case) or when your query and DB are not optimized to use an index for ORDER BY. However - I don't get the point of your question. No-one tells you, that `count(*)` is **always** faster. And it should be clear, that sometimes it's not. So what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 4):

[It still depends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/188682).

Since you want a general assessment, not specific to your query: You cannot make the general assumption that one of the methods will be faster. MySQL will treat each query indiviually, and if it finds a faster execution plan, it will use it.

Adding a `limit` can shorten the execution time if MySQL doesn't need all rows to give you the requested result.

- A trivial example is `select * from table limit 1`. MySQL can take the first row and then stop, as opposed to reading the whole table.
- A trivial counterexample is `select * from table order by some_unindexed_column limit 1`. MySQL has to read the whole table, order it, then return the first row.
- A trivial countermeasure to make the counterexample fast again is to add an index on `some_unindexed_column`. MySQL can now read the first entry from the index, read the corresponding row from the table and stop. (The two steps here are making this query slightly slower than the first one though).

Obviously, if adding a `limit` does not affect execution time (where I don't include the effect of having to send less rows to the client), `sql_calc_found_rows` doesn't affect it either.

Assessing the execution time for the related `count(*)`-query is harder to do generally, as it usually is just a different query, which is not directly comparable anymore. E.g. for `select count(*) from (select * from table order by some_unindexed_column) sub`, the `order by` is obviously superfluous, and you would just remove it if you write it by hand, and even if not, MySQL will, depending on your version, actually remove it itself.

So you would be actually running `select count(*) from table`.

Completely coincidental, this is also the related `count(*)`-query for `select * from table limit 1`

This count-query is faster than:

- `select * from table order by some_unindexed_column` as it doesn't need to do the ordering
- `select * from table order by some_unindexed_column limit 1` and `select sql_calc_found_rows * from table order by some_unindexed_column limit 1` as well as it doesn't need to do the ordering (and `sql_calc_found_rows` has no effect for this case)

It is slower than:
  - `select * from table limit 1` as it has to read all rows, whereas this query can stop after the first row
  - `select * from table order by indexed_column limit 1` as it has to read all rows, while the `limit` query can stop early using the *indexed*(!) column

A special, and probably only interesting, case, closely related to the situation in the [blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/) you read, is

```
select sql_calc_found_rows * from table order by indexed_column limit 1
```

This query will read the index, then use the index information to read the data from the original table (as it needs all columns). This 2-step-process is significantly slow. It is actually so slow, that MySQL itself can decide to not use an index if it suspects that it has to read a considerable percentage of rows from the original table. The `select count(*) from table` on the other hand does not need this 2-step-lookup.

This is basically the most relevant general case where a `count`-query performs better, and is exactly what happened in your blog.  YMMV, but the mentioned performance gain of factor 10 is possible this way, although it's usually less.

There is still a way to mitigate this problem: if you add a [covering index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index). If you e.g. have an index `(a,b,c)` and only select from those, e.g. `select b, c from table order by a`, this can happen completely within the index and does not need the 2-step-lookup.

Another case is a situation where `count(*)` allows MySQL to pick the smallest possible index. E.g. for a `select count(*) from table`, MySQL can pick any available index on that table, and for a small index, you need to read less bytes. Which is faster then reading more bytes. (I'll ignore that for MyISAM-tables, the count is stored in a table and can be looked up instantly).

There are probably a more situations (or things like `select very_expensive_function(a) from table`, which obviously gets faster if you do not executing the function), which can give you a benefit or not.

To sum up:

- if a `limit` does not change the execution speed, adding `sql_calc_found_rows` has no effect, and running an additionally `count(*)` query will obviously just add more time.
- if a `limit` does change the execution speed, then adding `sql_calc_found_rows` will make it slower. If running an additionally `count(*)` is faster than adding `sql_calc_found_rows` depends on the query.

It is worth noting that this analysis was for a really trivial query. The more complex your query gets, the less likely it is that the `count`-version is (just by luck) faster than `sql_calc_found_rows`. It will also depend on your MySQL version.

According to your description, your query currently falls in the first category, and if MySQL does not find a way to optimize the `count`-version on it's own, it is expected that it will take about the same time as the original one (which will just double the total time for both queries). Anything more specific (and especially if you need help optimizing your query) requires a look at your specific query.

Comment: Wow, thank you for this detailed explanation. I had a look at my tables, and found out that first table and some other joined tables actually had MyISAM specified as sql engine. Since I was working with existing database and did not create those tables myself, I had little insight into each specific table details. I will try adding indexes on ordered columns to see if it changes anything and will get back here to report results. Also I will try to submit trimmed sql queries and create table statements to illustrate the issue without dumping too much unrelated information.